# From JavaScript, Trigger Native Code Function

Tags: android, ios, native, cordova, analytics

I have a PhoneGap app that is using the Localytics services and I would like to track a certain event, so from the Javascript code at a certain moment I would like to call a native function with a few parameters. This native function would then call the event tracking function from Localytics like so:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary =
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     @"miles per hour",
     @"display units",
     @"yes",
     @"blank screen",
     nil];
[[LocalyticsSession sharedLocalyticsSession] tagEvent:@"Options saved" attributes:dictionary];
```

Do you have an example of native code being called from JS and passing parameters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of examples of JavaScript -> Java calls in the Phonegap plugins at https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins